# R barplot with y-axis greater than zero

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot some data in R.

the table look like:

```
Name     Count
A        110
B        120
C        130
```

I want to plot this table which each column is `Name` and the bar height is `Count`. I also want to zoom to important part from 100 to 150 because all values in `Count` is greater than 100.

I think we could set the y-axis base to 100 in this case. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I hope you realize this may be very misleading. You may be doing your audience a dishonest favor if you plan on showing small differences atop very high bars. They may appear "significant", however looked from afar, a comparison may yield a different conclusion.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Thank for your comment. In this case, I want to plot a table which Count is greater than one million and the difference between values is very small so It is better to zoom to important part. After that, I could see the difference between bars in chart.

Comment: In that case, a point is much more appropriate than a bar. The shape of the bar falsely implies that it begins at the bottom of the plot, which it in fact does not. Points don't convey that same implication. I agree with Roman's point: a bar chart is misleading. You would do the audience a favor by choosing a different way of presenting the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
m1 <- matrix(df1[,2], ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, df1[,1]))
barplot(m1, ylim=c(100,150), beside=TRUE, xpd=FALSE)
```

[image]
Or

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Name, y=Count))+
               geom_bar(stat='identity')+
               coord_cartesian(ylim=c(100,150)) +
               theme_bw() +
               xlab(NULL) +
               ylab(NULL)
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Count = c(110L, 120L, 
130L)), .Names = c("Name", "Count"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```